# How to prove this vector identity

Tags: multivariable-calculus, cross-product

How do i prove this vector identity ?

$$(\vec a \times \vec b)\times \vec c=(\vec a \cdot\vec c)\vec b - (\vec b\cdot\vec c)\vec a$$

Comment: The left hand side is orthogonal to $\vec c$, the right hand side is a linear combination of $\vec a$ and $\vec b$. So equality can hold at most if $\vec c\perp \vec a,\vec b$. On second reading, what is $(\vec a\cdot \vec b)\times \vec c$ supposed to mean in the first place?

Comment: The left-hand side makes no sense as written.

Comment: The equality is true. I want to know how to prove it

Comment: @UmbertoP. Sorry, there was a typo. it will make sense now

Comment: [Here you can find a proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Vector_triple_product)

Comment: downvoting because OP don't show any try to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

This is called vector triple product expansion . This is a well known formula. Proof is available at

Text proof : http://padante.com/scalar-and-vector-triple-product/

Video online proof taught by khan :
https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/vectors_and_spaces/dot_cross_products/v/vector-triple-product-expansion--very-optional

Answer (score 1):

La demostración es standar y supongo que resulta clara. Hay una forma de ver las cosas que quizá te aporte algo: el triple producto es ortogonal a $\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b}$ y por tanto está en el plano generado por $\mathbf{a}$ y $\mathbf{b}$. Por eso la única aportación para el cálculo es la de $\mathbf{c}$, y concretamente la de la proyección de $\mathbf{c}$ sobre el plano $\mathbf{ab}$, que tiene como componentes $\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{c}$ (por lo que respecta a $\mathbf{a}$)  y  $\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{c}$ (por lo que respecta a b), es decir, el vector $(\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{c})\mathbf{a} + (\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{c})\mathbf{b}$.  Y es ortogonal a esa proyección (porque es ortogonal a $\mathbf{c}$), por tanto es o bien el vector $(\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{c})\mathbf{b} - (\mathbf{c} \cdot \mathbf{b})\mathbf{a}$  o bien su opuesto (se intercambian la componentes y se cambia una de signo).  La orientación dada por el producto vectorial conduce a elegir entre las dos posibles la forma correcta. En el fondo esto es lo que se esconde tras la demostración formal.

[image]